# How did Qi'ra get to Crimson Dawn?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, star-wars, solo-a-star-wars-story

In *Solo: A Star Wars Story*, we see that Han meets Qi'ra at Crimson Dawn and he is pleasantly surprised by her presence there. He keeps asking her how she got out in one scene, and in another he asks 'what's their future?' to which Qi'ra responds saying she is not the same anymore and she has done some bad things and everyone serves someone etc.

How exactly does she get to Crimson Dawn from Corellia? Does the brand on her wrist signify that she is engaged to Dryden Vos as in few scenes we see that Qi'ra is not just any lieutenant but more to Dryden Vos?

Comment: I would say that she was sold after getting arrested (hence the branding), and used her 'advantages' to get in the position she is now.

Answer (score 1):

Qi'ra was sold by the White Worms to the Crimson Dawn.

From [this article](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/heat-vision/solo-darth-maul-cameo-undermined-qi-ra-character-arc-1117058)

> Throughout the film, Qi’ra attempts to protect Han from the truth about the life she's led in the three years since his escape and her arrest on their home planet of Corellia. While he's continued to dream of buying a ship and returning to rescue her, **she's been sold to Crimson Dawn, the most ruthless crime syndicate during the Empire’s reign. She works for Dryden Vos (Paul Bettany), and has committed unspeakable crimes on his behalf.**

From [Star Wars databank](https://www.starwars.com/databank/qi-ra),

> But Qi’ra was a survivor. She managed to escape Corellia after all, rising in the ranks of the crime syndicate Crimson Dawn to become Dryden Vos’s most-trusted lieutenant.

The brand on her wrist signifies that she has an allegiance towards this gang, not Dryden Vos, which we can see at the end of the film when she leaves Solo and contacts the syndicates real head honcho: the Sith Lord Darth Maul. This is what Darth Maul says,

> Bring the ship and come to me on Dathomir and you and I will then decide  what to do about the traitor, Beckett, and his accomplices. I'm on my way. Qi'ra, you and I will be working much more closely from now on.

<sub>[Source](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=solo-a-star-wars-story)</sub>